# How can I select Python 3.7 or Python 3.8 in iPython?

Tags: python, ipython

My OS is *Windows 7*

I need to use *TensorFlow* with *Keras* in *Python*, but it doesn't work yet in *Python 3.8*. So I've installed again *Python 3.7* and his packages.

Inside the IDE *PyCharm* was easy. It just add another interpreter in settings and it works. So when I create a project I need to select the right interpreter.

I also use *iPython* to make small tests. I've searched in all *Stackoverflow* and I don't find any answer that works in 2020.  I use *iPython* and not the *Jupyter* environment.

First, I've created the kernels, as iPython instructions said in its site.

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

It creates a `json` file in  `c:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels`

After I use `iPython -h` and he told me to use *kernel* subcommand:

```
Subcommands are launched as `ipython cmd [args]`. For information on using
subcommand 'cmd', do: `ipython cmd -h`.
```

Feeling more motivated, I've tried the command `iPython kernel -h`. But I've got a very confusing text.

So I've tried to use the `kernel` option,

```
C:> iPython kernel
```

It gave me the following message:

```
To connect another client to this kernel, use:
    --existing kernel-3404.json
```

However, I'm not getting select the right kernel.

I try to use use my kernel file, but with no success.

```
Invalid argument: '--kernel.json'
```

So I'm lost, because in no place I've found a detailed instructions for kernel subcommand in line command options for *iPython*.

Comment: I would recommend using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) or [virtualenv](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) to simplify and isolate the change of python versions and packages when needed. Have a look at them ;D

Comment: `Anaconda` is very heavy, I've found some bugs and I quit. `VirtualEnv` I give a try, I've installed 2 virtual environment, but with no success. It works with Jupyter but not with iPython.

Comment: in theory, `ipykernel` was a simpler form made by Jupyter/iPython developers for making possible comute the Python version easily.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that solves my problem in  Windows 7. I don't even need `ipyKernet` package.

I've started locating `iPython.exe` files in *Python 3.7* and *Python 3.8*

```
c:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\ipython.exe 
c:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\ipython.exe
```

So I've made the following script `py.BAT` and stored it in a folder inside the PATH environment variable (One can edit the PATH variable using `Control Panel`, `Systems`,  `Advanced system settings`, `environment variables`):

```
@echo off
cd\dropbox\python
if "%1"=="37" goto ip37
if "%1"=="38" goto ip38
if not "%1"== "" goto erro
:ip38
  c:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\ipython
  goto fim
:ip37
  c:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\ipython
  goto fim
:erro
  echo Syntax: py 37   - iPython 3.7 
  echo         py 38   - iPython 3.8
  echo         py      - iPython 3.8
:fim
```

Now it's a piece of cake:

If I want to run *iPython* over *Python 3.7*

```
py 37
```

If I what to run *iPython* over *Python 3.8*

```
py
```

or

```
py 38
```

Of course I've checked  Python version in each *iPython* session:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

The messages was

```
3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

or

```
3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30)[MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Any other param

```
py 40 # e.g.
```

results in

```
Syntax: py 37   - iPython 3.7
        py 38   - iPython 3.8
        py      - iPython 3.8
```

Internal references in Python don't use `PATH` environment variables in general, but when one uses an utility in the shell as `pip`, has a problem because if you write `pip` in the shell, it searchs the first executable in the order of the string content in the `PATH` variable, generally the last *Python* version.

So one has to make a copy in the old  *Python* version that utility in the same folder (please not rename the original file) with another name (Eg: `pip.exe` to `pi.exe`)

Other solution would be temporarily change the path environment variable inside `PY.BAT` and any other, if necessary. I haven't done it yet because everything is fine so far.